# open content page as jquery dialog in another content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I am working on a asp.net web application which was created with asp.net master/content pages. Here i am opening a `window.open()` to open the selected record from grid. Everything is working fine.

**Code:**

```
window.open(fileName, (new Date()).getMilliseconds(), 'width=' + wndWidth + ',height=' + wndHeight + ', left=' + wndX + ', top=' + wndY + ', toolbar=0, location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, modal=yes');
```

**Problem:**

Now i have to open this content page in jquery dialog. I cannot use separate page to show it in jquery dialog due to some restrictions. how i can open this content page as jquery dialog.

**My tried code so far:**

```
 var $panel = $('#dialog');
 $.ajax({
            url: fileName,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            beforesend: ShowLoader(),
            async: true,
            success: function (obj) {
                HideLoader();
                $panel.dialog({
                    height: 700,
                    width: 500
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'title'

                });
                $panel.html(obj);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                HideLoader();
                alert('Error in process please try again.');
            }
        });
```

Comment: use `jquery-ui` dialog

Comment: Try changing the place of  $panel.html(obj); and $panel.dialog()